# Receiving UDP packages with python 3.6 doesn't work when using script files

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, udp

I have a strange problem regarding sockets in Python. I'm using Windows 7 and the portable winpython with Python 3.6.

I want to recive UDP messages from a server in a local network, that sends every second a package containing a simple string. When I type the following code in the interactive ipython shell everything works quite well and I can receive a singel package:

```
import socket as s

host = "10.20.1.0"   # IP address of server
port = 7071

SOCK = s.socket(s.AF_INET, s.SOCK_DGRAM)
SOCK.settimeout(5.0)

SOCK.bind( ("", port) )
SOCK.connect( (host, port) )

SOCK.recv( buffer )
```

The problem is that I do not receive anything when I put the same lines in a script an run it with "python my_script.py" from shell. I am absolutely clueless why this does not work...do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Max